# Population Dynamics problem concerning Allee Effect

Tags: population-dynamics

I am reading Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos with Applications to Physics, Biology, Chemistry, and Engineering, 2nd Ed. (Strogatz 2015).  I came across a problem involving the Allee Effect which I have not been able to solve.
Problem:  [image: Strogatz problem]

I tried comparing terms with the Allee effect as stated on Wikipedia, [image: allee effect equation] but it is still not clear to me how to solve this.  Can someone please help?

Since my last post, I have tried plotting several values for the parameters, and I solved for the zeros of this equation.  My guess, is that I am supposed to qualitatively analyze this plot and see that it is maximized for intermediate values of N.  I am including a picture from Mathematica of my work.  Please let me know if I am on the wrong track.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're not interpreting that Wikipedia page correctly. That equation provides an example of the Allee effect, but is not exclusive.

The Allee effect occurs when the non-zero steady state of a system is not globally attractive, so that such populations may be stable at non-zero population levels for a long time, but are unable to recover once the population density drops below a certain threshold.

In terms of your problem, the tricky bit (conditions for global attraction) is done for you as it instructs you to find parameters so that $\frac{\dot{N}}{N}$ is **maximum** for intermediate (*positive*) $N$.

So when does $f(N) = r - a(N-b)^2$ have a maximum admitted at some positive $N$? This is a quadratic, so simple mathematics is enough.

- $a>0$ is needed to ensure the parabola admits a maximum
- $b>0$ is needed for the maximum is attained at positive $N$.
- $r>0$ is also needed to ensure the maximum is positive. This is not clear from the information in the question, but the non-trivial steady states involve $\sqrt{\frac{r}{a}}$ and so $r > 0$ for these steady states to even exist.

So overall quite boring conditions and not a very satisfying question.

---

In general, a population $x$ with reproductive rate $b(x)$ and death rate $d(x)$ with dynamics $$\frac{dx}{dt} = x(b(x) - d(x))$$ displays the Allee effect if $b(0) < d(0)$. This is easy to prove with a basic grasp of ODE stability.

Comment: Thank you!  It is quite clear, now!